# Suse 12.3 install tomcat

Tags: python, opensuse-12.2, yast

Hi i have a fresh suse 12.3 installation.

when i try to install python, i get a error.

```
Problems
patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-conflicts-12.3-7.10.1.i586 conflicts with python provided by python-2.7.3-10.8.1.i586
```

should i uninstall patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-conflicts-12.3-7.10.1.i586?

Comment: are you using a Suse 12.3 repo to get python?

Comment: i didn't change any repo from the original installation